IC 74HC08 can the output drive the input without destroying it?
i made a circuit with  a 74HC08 and i wanted that when the output is high(1Y) it would take over contact (1B) with a led between it .and the input B connected to  ground with a 20K resistor it works fine like i want to, but i can't find anywhere if you can connect the output on the input of a IC and break it after time?
Is this possible?


(Do not leave inputs of C-MOS logic ICs unconnected.)

Within one "logic family" (like HC), (gate) outputs are meant to be suitable to drive a number of inputs. Please clarify in the body of your question: Is the LED between 1Y and 1B intended to emit human visible light? Is the 5 V on J6 related to GND&VCC? How? I see input B connected to ground with a 20 K resistor, but the other side of the resistors labelled 20K is connected to terminal 1 of J6. How shall [can you] connect the output on the input of [an] IC and break it after time? be understood, especially: What does the it there refer to?

When your 1Y output drives HIGH, the 74HC08 5 V supply must be dropped across three things in its series circuit:

The 74HC08 1Y internal output stage (see its datasheet)
The LED (see its datasheet for voltage drop at a certain current)
The current limiting resistor

The resistor value is selected to set the LED current to something (a) the 74HC08 1Y output stage is capable of and (b) that gives the wanted LED brilliance if possible.
As an example, let's assume the LED current is 1 mA, the LED drops 2.1 V and the 1Y output stage drops 0.4 V. That leaves 2.5 V across the series resistor. That's well above the 1B threshold for a logic HIGH so the LED on will always drive 1B HIGH. When the SW11 is pressed, 1B will also be driven HIGH. Only when SW11 is released and 1Y drives LOW will 1B be pulled LOW by its resistor.
Your present 20K pull-down is far too high to allow 1 mA of LED current, so it won't glow much. The resistor can be changed to 2K2, allowing just over 1 mA with the above example characteristics.
Neither the current circuit nor this revised one would damage the 74HC08.
But your current question doesn't state your application, so it's not possible to say if it can be done better or if this gives the function you need.
There's something else for you to consider. Unlike normal diodes, a lot of LEDs can only withstand a low reverse voltage, often less than 2.5 V. Look up VRRM in your LED's datasheet. When SW11 is pressed and 1Y is driving LOW, LED D5 will have a reverse of about 4.7 V across it and may be damaged.

How on earth did you decipher the question to provide an answer? You’ve always been good at that.

thanks TonyM,
your explanation is exacly what i need.i will change configuration

@BlairFonville, thank your for the kind words and the answer is: with a lot of reading and re-reading :-D

the 74HC08 5 V supply the question does not tell VCC. If it is 5 V, $V_{IH}min$ would be about 3.5 V. (Thinking of HCT?)
